# Prevent Resource [.resx] files from precompiling. .NET Core 2.0

Tags: localization, asp.net-core-2.0

I am working on a project which uses Resource [.resx] file to handle some culture specified texts.

When we publish the project those .resx files get compiled to .dll file. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

I want .resx files to be kept as same after publish.

Answer (score 1):

Take the property of resource file and set Build Action to 'None'.

[image]

Comment: But, Now it is just discarding the chnages, i need the .resx files to working.

Comment: Sorry, this will only generate the resx file as is while publishing.